# Play Framework 2.2 dependancies not downloading where I expect them to

Tags: java, maven, playframework, sbt

I just got a new computer and installed play 2.2.x and pulled my project from git and everything was going fine until I tried to add apache commons-email jars. I added the following to my build.sbt

```
org.apache.commons" % "commons-email" % "1.3.3"
```

and loaded up my play app. It said it was successfully downloaded, but when i tried using the library, I saw that it wasn't there. I checked the directory where all the jars are:

```
play2.2.1/repository/local
```

and saw that org.apache.commons was there, but only commons-compress, commons-exec and commons-langs were there. After searching for the commons-email directory, I see that it is in my repository/cache directory. I can't seem to find anything online as to why it isn't being downloaded correctly into my repository/local directory. can anyone assist me and let me know why this is happening so I can avoid this in the future? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are using some IDE, like eclipse you need to recreate play project as eclipse project so that it can resolve all dependencies.